# content fill UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

The thing that I would like to achieve is a horizontal scrollview. In this scrollview, I have five buttons and four imageviews alternating. The button width is always different, because they are getting there text programmatically. The imageview has static width (50).

The problem is, when the buttons are too small, the scrollview isn't filled. When the buttons are bigger, it should be scrollable.

How do I achieve that?

(working with autolayout and not with swift)

Comment: Did you read the apple guide? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a uiview as a container so that your view hierarchy looks like this:

scrollview
-- uiview (container)
---- button
---- imageview
---- button
---- imageview
---- button
---- imageview
---- button

then you can set up an equal width constraint between the container view and the scrollview and set its relation to "greater than or equal".
you also have to decide if you (1) make the buttons equal width or (2) setup different hugging priorities.

let me know if you need some more help.

Comment: I had the container but didn't set it to "greater than or equal". Sometimes it can be so easy. Thanks!